# Есть ли в dot.net что-то для работы с сетевыми пакетами?

Tags: c#

Вопрос теоретический, если какой нибудь инструмент где можно  работать с сетевыми пакетами. Допустим, поймать пакет сетевой, и заменить в нем заголовок. Суть в том, прочитал материалы конференции, где описывается способ подмены пакетов в трафике со спутника обычной картой для приема спутникового интернета. Вот озадачился  поиском хорошего инструмента.

Comment: [Telerik FiddlerCore](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler/fiddlercore) ?

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо,я не знал о такой штуке. Буду смотреть.

Comment: [Pcap](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pcap)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Спасибо, очень интересно.